# Syntax Error in Simple Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

> Error: unexpected token '(' on line number-3

```
trigger updatephone on Account (after insert) {

    List<Account> acc=new.List<Account>();
    for(contact c:trigger.new)
    {
        Account a=[select id, phone from account where Id=c.accountid];
        a.phone=c.phone;
        acc.add(a);
    }
    update acc;
}
```

Comment: So what's the error...too many SOQL queries?

Comment: Error: unexpected token '(' on line number-3

Comment: You should just put this functionality in a `Workflow Rule` with a `Field Update`.

Comment: Did you mean for `List<Account> acc = new.List<Account>()` to have the full-stop between `new` and `List<Account>()`, or is it a typo?

Comment: you have to remove the '.' between new and List<Account>() and line 3 as in List<Account> acc= new List<Account>(); As metioned in the above comment you should go for a workflow on a contact and create a field update to get this functionality done.

Comment: You also have a type conflict in your for loop. You're trying to loop over contacts, but `Trigger.new` is a `List<Account>` here.

Comment: Yes.. i am working on that now

Comment: @Suresh, you should look into trying the [Apex trigger Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_intro). Its good way to get accustomed to the platform, and learn the basics of writing apex triggers.

Answer (score 3):

This trigger is **all over the place** and raises a lot of questions that you should be asking yourself.

1. What happens if there are no contacts during insert (i.e., the Account was inserted manually, rather than converted from a lead)?
2. What happens in the event of more than one contact under the account? Which phone number takes priority, or do we just draw from a hat?
3. You should never do a SOQL Query inside a loop - you're going to hit the governor limit in no time flat using this approach
4. Your Trigger.new context is ACCOUNT because this trigger is on the Account object, but you are doing a for() loop of contacts while trying to loop through a list of accounts. This won't work. You'd need to query the contacts first (outside of the loop) using SOQL
5. If all this trigger serves to accomplish is copying the phone number from a Contact record, it could be handled using **Workflow Rules** and **Field Updates** on the child object (Contact) to update the Parent (Account) whenever the contact is edited or the phone number is changed.

Lots of other potential questions, but these are some basics. I think you are overthinking this. Remember, Salesforce's mantra is `clicks not code` so we should avoid using apex whenever declarative functionality in the platform is available to accomplish the same task. Workflow rules aren't subject to the same restrictions as apex.

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with your trigger.

The compilation error that you're getting

> Error: unexpected token '(' on line number-3

is because there's a period (full-stop) between 'new' and 'List();`

Line 3 should be `List<Account> acc = new List<Account>();`

Beyond that, there are two issues with your for loop.

First, you want to loop over `Contact` records, and use `Trigger.new`. The issue here is that in an `Account` trigger, `Trigger.new` will be a `List<Account>`.

Second, you have a query inside of a loop, which is never a good idea. If you were to insert more than 100 accounts (say, through the Apex DataLoader), you would run into the query governor limit.

The general pattern for extracting a query from inside of a loop is

1. Create a collection (set, map, or list) to hold Ids
2. Loop over `Trigger.new` to populate the collection of Ids from the previous step
3. Run your query, using the collection of Ids from step 1, and then loop over the results

In your case here, you can actually skip the first two steps. `Trigger.newMap.keySet()` contains this information.

The following example should illustrate better practices for writing triggers, though I'm fairly certain it won't work (as it's rather difficult to have contacts on an `Account` before the `Account` has been inserted)

```
trigger updatephone on Account (after insert) {
    // Since we're looking to update account(s), and we're in an After trigger,
    //   creating a list to store the updated account information is correct
    List<Account> acc = new List<Account>();

    // Since we're working on Accounts here, we need to query for the related Contacts.
    // There is more than one way to do this.
    // An Account can have more than one Contact, but we can only put one contact's
    //   phone number on the Account.
    // The simplest way to handle this is to have a Map<Id, String>, where the Id
    //   id the Account's Id
    Map<Id, String> accountIdToContactPhone = new Map<Id, String>();

    // Here, we can just use Trigger.newMap.keySet() in the query.
    // In other situations, you may need to make a separate List or Set
    //   and have another for loop before this one
    for(Contact cntct :[SELECT AccountId, Phone FROM Contact WHERE AccountId IN :trigger.newMap.keySet()){

        // This logic could be changed, I'm just going with the simplest method here
        //   (Always overwrite data in the map)
        accountIdToContactPhone.put(cntct.AccountId, cntct.Phone);
    }

    for(Account acct :trigger.new)
    {
        // This is the reason why we needed to make that map in the loop above.
        // Trying to access a Contact for a specific account would be hard,
        //   but we have easy access to the Account Id.
        // The map we created earlier maps an Account Id to a contact's Phone number,
        //   exactly what we're looking for!

        // There's also no need to re-query for the Accounts.
        // We can use the sObject constructor with name/value pairs
        acc.add(new Account(
            Id = acct.Id,
            Phone = accountIdToContactPhone.get(acct.Id)
        ));
    }

    // Keeping DML outside of loops is also important
    update acc;
}
```